# Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'/Int object is not iterable

Tags: python

I am having trouble fixing the problem of ensuring that a string is not being multiplied by a float. When I do attempt to fix it by not changing the type to str(), I end up with another error that is "'int' object is not iterable". May I please know how to resolve this error and why putting int() isn't working?

```
def filter_wave(wave,n):
new_wave=[]
for i in range(len(wave)):
    if i==0:
        new_wave.extend(str(int(wave[i]*0.6+wave[i+1]*0.2)))
    if i==len(wave):
        new_wave.extend(str(int(wave[i-1]*0.2+wave[i+1]*0.2)))
    else:
        new_wave.extend(str(int(wave[i-1]*0.2+wave[i]*0.6)))
if n==0:
    return wave
else:
    return filter_wave(new_wave,n-1)

filter_wave([0, 3, 7, 14, 18, 24, 23, 29, 28, 30, 32, 35, 31, 34, 32, 30, 25, 25, 24, 23, 18, 14, 15, 14, 12, 12, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5, 6, 4, 2, 2, 3, -1, -5, -4, -9, -9, -14, -16, -17, -18, -23, -24, -25, -25, -23, -20, -20, -16, -17, -11, -7, -7, 0, 3, 6, 8, 15, 18, 19, 24, 27, 24, 28, 25, 29, 27, 26, 22, 20, 16, 13, 13, 11, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, -3, -6, -6, -7, -6, -5, -7, -6, -6, -6, -6, -7, -9, -13, -11, -17, -16, -22, -24, -23, -27, -29, -30, -34, -33, -34, -37, -34, -32, -33, -28, -28, -23, -18, -13, -10, -8, 0, 3, 10, 12, 15, 22, 22, 27, 29, 31, 31, 29, 31, 27, 26, 27, 24, 20, 17, 17, 14, 11, 12, 8, 6, 5, 8, 6, 3, 6, 7, 4, 7, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 0, -2, -3, -6, -7, -12, -14, -16, -15, -18, -21, -22, -23, -26, -26, -22, -23, -21, -18, -13, -9, -8, -3, -1, 6, 10, 12, 17, 20, 23, 25, 28, 30, 30, 30, 27, 25, 26, 24, 19, 18, 17, 12, 12, 8, 7, 4, 0, -2, -2, -1, -1, -6, -4, -4, -3, -5, -7, -8, -5, -5, -7, -10, -10, -12, -17, -17, -22, -21, -25, -29, -29, -32, -35, -34, -32, -33, -33, -33, -33, -28, -24, -22, -18, -15, -9, -6, 0, 6, 9, 11, 16, 22, 22, 24, 25, 29, 30, 31, 28, 29, 27, 22, 22, 20, 16, 17, 15, 14, 10, 10, 6, 8, 4, 4, 7, 4, 7, 7, 6, 6, 3, 7, 2, 2, 4, 1, 0, -2, -3, -7, -8, -13, -14, -16],2)
```

Comment: What's the reason for the str of the value [i.e. str(int(wave[i-1]*0.2+wave[i+1]*0.2))]?

Comment: I was just trying to resolve the "int object is not iterable" error. I'm still doing a trial and error method to debug my code.

Comment: But the code works if you remove the str and change extend to append.  Also, the conditional with i==len(wave) will never be true, since i is at most len(wave)-1.

Comment: Oh yes! The range. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you meant to use `append`, not `extend`:

```
new_wave.append(your_var)
```

`append` adds the given element to the list

`extend` adds the elements of a given iterable to the list

Comment: Thank you for the correction! I will keep this in mind from now onwards.